# If $p, q, r$ are the roots of $x^3 -x+1=0$, what is $p^5 + q^5 + r^5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Can someone please help us solve this equation. It was on our college entry exam, but no one managed to solve it. The problem is:

> Let $p,q,r$ be the roots of $x^3 -x+1=0$.  Then $p^5+q^5+r^5 = ?$

Correct answer was $-5$, but no one managed to solve this problem. We tried different methods, but none came up with a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If its any consolation i got stuck as well and im in a third year honors program for math.  understanding where and why the first line of lulu's answer comes from is really the important bit to solving the question. (which i personally didnt know till the end of a second year abstract algebra course in university) so i wouldn't be too concerned that you didnt find this result.

Comment: Yes but this was on college entry exam, and we are all high school how should we be able to solve this when we dont even understand how to factorize

Comment: im not sure how one would solve this using a high school approach for one two of the roots are imaginary and the only other root is irrational. i guess if you knew the cubic formula you could find the 3 roots and then just plug them in the roots will look something like $-\frac {\sqrt 3}{2} $ and $ \frac {\sqrt 3}{4}  + \frac {\sqrt 3}{4}i $ and its complex pair subing those in would give you a rough estimate of the value  or an exact one if you used the cubic formula. Not that i would recommend approaching it this way but it would be something a highschool student could do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the cubic we deduce that $$p+q+r=0\quad \&\quad pq+qr+pr=-1$$

Note, for example, that $$p^3=p-1\implies p^5=p^3.p^2=p^2(p-1)=p^3-p^2=-p^2+p-1$$  It follows that $$p^5+q^5+r^5=-(p^2+q^2+r^2)-3$$

Now $$p+q+r=0\implies 0=(p+q+r)^2=p^2+q^2+r^2+2(pq+pr+qr)\implies p^2+q^2+r^2=2$$ and the desired result follows at once.

Comment: I dont understand how come p^3=p-1 and from there  p^5=p^3-p2 ? This doesnt make any sense to me sorry, I am still highschool so I dont understand

Comment: $p^3=p-1$ as p is a root of the polynomial, substitute it in and rearrange.

Comment: you can also multiply $p^2$ on both sides

Comment: Sorry I was away from my computer.  Since $p$ is a root of the cubic, we have $p^3-p+1=0$ or $p^3=p-1$.  Multiplying both sides by $p^2$ we get $p^5=p^3-p^2$.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: Side note:  I think this problem is quite hard for high school.  the idea is simple enough, if you are used to this sort of thing.  The coefficients of the cubic give you three symmetric functions in the three roots, and it turns out that you can write any other polynomial symmetric function in terms of these.  Of course, in my argument I wrote everything out explicitly so I never had to fall back on a general theorem.

Comment: Oh thank you very much now it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative approach: the characteristic polynomial of
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
is exactly $p(x)=x^3-x+1$, since $M$ is the companion matrix of $p(x)$.
  It follows that the wanted sum is
$$ p^5+q^5+r^5=\text{Tr }\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^5 = \text{Tr }\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -2 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}=\color{red}{-5}. $$

Answer (score 5):

For any three numbers $p$, $q$, and $r$, $p^5+q^5+r^5$ is equal to\begin{multline*}(p+q+r)^5-5 (p q+p r+q r) (p+q+r)^3+5 p q r (p+q+r)^2+\\+5 (p q+p r+q r)^2(p+q+r)-5 p q r (p q+p r+q r).\end{multline*}Since $p+q+r=0$, $pq+pr+qr=-1$, and $pqr=-1$,$$p^5+q^5+r^5=-5\times(-1)\times(-1)=-5.$$

**Added note:** The way I used to express $p^5+q^5+r^5$ in function of $p+q+r$, $pq+pr+qr$, and $pqr$ was this: as a first step, I saw that the greatest power of $p$ in this expression was $p^5$ and that there was no $q$ and no $r$ here. So, I subtracted $(p+q+r)^5$ from my expression, obtaining\begin{multline*}-5 p^4 q-5 p^4 r-10 p^3 q^2-20 p^3 q r-10 p^3 r^2-10 p^2 q^3-30 p^2 q^2 r-30 p^2 q r^2+\\-10 p^2 r^3-5 p q^4-20 p q^3 r-30 p q^2 r^2-20 p q r^3-5 p r^4-5 q^4 r-10 q^3 r^2-10 q^2 r^3-5 q r^4.\end{multline*}Now, the greatest power of $p$ is $p^4$, and among those monomials with $p^4$, the one with the greatest power of $q$ is $-5p^4q=-5p^3(pq)$. So, now I add $5(p+q+r)^3(pq+pr+qr)$ to my expression, getting\begin{multline*}5 p^3 q^2+15 p^3 q r+5 p^3 r^2+5 p^2 q^3+30 p^2 q^2 r+30 p^2 q r^2+5 p^2 r^3+\\+15 p q^3 r+30 p q^2 r^2+15 p q r^3+5 q^3 r^2+5 q^2 r^3\end{multline*}

I suppose that by now you got the pattern. At this point, the greatest power of $p$ is $p^3$, and among those monomials with $p^3$, the one with the greatest power of $q$ is $5p^3q^2=5p(pq)^2$. So, now I subtract $5(p+q+r)(pq+pr+qr)^2$ from my expression, getting$$5 p^3 q r+5 p^2 q^2 r+5 p^2 q r^2+5 p q^3 r+5 p q^2 r^2+5 p q r^3\text,$$and so on.

Comment: Wow nice ... but how did you manage to factorize p^5+q^5+r^5 is there any formula you used for that I would really like to know cause i tried to factorize it but failed ...

Comment: Google for Elementary Symmetric Polynomials. If you don't find the algorithm, I will try to help you. But I will be able to do it only within a few hours.

Comment: I searched for it but I still dont understabd how did you get all that ... I am still in high school so all this is new to me.

Comment: No problem. Within a few hours I will add a note to my answer to explain how I got that expression.